# Как задать время для повторного выполнения кода в PHP?

Tags: php

Имеется функция, при первом выполнении - функция должна срабатываться, а при повторном его выполнение должно пройти 5-секунд со времени первого срабатывания функции (обращения к нему), как это можно реализовать в PHP? Возможно session, time()? Приведите пример пожалуйста

Comment: Что вы хотите реализовать конкретно? На `php` такой функции нет. Можно запустить бесконечный цикл + `sleep`.

Comment: Суть в том что у меня имеется кнопка в формате ссылки "<a href="/page-r" id="r-id">Оформить</a>", при первой нажатии происходит обработка со стороны php - if (page){тут целая строка кода }, но случается так что пользователь после нажатия ожидает около 4-секунд, некотрые не ожидая нажимают по 2-3 раза и получается так что по данные передаются повтором

Comment: Вам скорее на javascript это нужно, а не php. Просто делаете (а)синхронный запрос на туже ссылку что стоит в атрибуте href. И после первого нажатия на кнопку, делаете неактивной кнопку, пока не придет ответ от первого нажатия (во время ожидания, показываете анимацию, заранее подгруженную в кеш, если это изображение, ну или на css). И не изобретайте велосипед

Comment: просто после нажатия блокируйте кнопку, нарисуйте иконку, которая крутится, чтобы человек знал, что что-то происходит.

Comment: @noname2019 не помогает ничего

Comment: Редактируйте вопрос, выложите Ваши попытки и покажите где именно не получается.